# Why is gContextMenu null?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

This is a condensed version of my code.
I was trying to show a menu item in the right-click context menu of firefox.

Here **gContextMenu** is showing up as null, and it screws up the firefox's context menu. 
I found this out after 2 days of debugging.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css" type="text/css"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://foobar/skin/foobar.css" type="text/css"?>

<!DOCTYPE window SYSTEM "chrome://foobar/locale/foobar.dtd">

<overlay id="foobar-browser-overlay"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">



    <stringbundleset id="stringbundleset">
    <stringbundle id="foobar-string-bundle" src="chrome://foobar/locale/foobar.properties"/>
    </stringbundleset>

    <popup id="contentAreaContextMenu" onpopupshowing="alert(gContextMenu)">
        <menuseparator />
        <menuitem id="foobar-show-meaning" label="&foobar.showmeaning.label;"  />
    </popup>
</overlay>
```

Note:
  I am referring to http://kb.mozillazine.org/Adding_items_to_menus to add a menuItem  to the firefox's context menu, shown only when text is selected. But after debugging, the root cause is found to be gContextMenu is null.

1. My firefox version is **19.0.2**
2. I don't want to use the new addon-sdk because it is bereft of finer controls which I plan to add later. (Finer controls like - controlling window size, its x,y co-ordinates)
3. I am a novice when it comes to XUL development as of now..
4. My references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial,
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/PopupGuide/Extensions,
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/PopupGuide/ContextMenus#Hiding_and_Showing_Menu_Items_based_on_Context

Answer (score 1):

The popup element has been deprecated long time ago, change your overlay accordingly

```
<menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu"
...
</menupopup>
```

Also don't use the inline event handler, probably it overwrites the original. [Add an event listener programmatically](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Adding_items_to_menus#Dynamically_showing_context_menu_items).

Comment: This does not work! It still shows null as an alert! X(
This is my new code..  

`     <menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu" onpopupshowing="alert(gContextMenu)">
      <menuseparator />
      <menuitem id="foobar-show-meaning" label="&foobar.showmeaning.label;"  />
     </menupopup>`